# Getting Top 10 based on column value

Tags: sql-server, database

I have a code that output a long list of the sum of count of work orders per name and sorts it by total, name and count:

```
;with cte as (
SELECT [Name],
        [Emergency],
        count([Emergency]) as [CountItem]
FROM tableA
GROUP BY [Name], [Emergency])

select Name,[Emergency],[Count],SUM([CountItem]) OVER(PARTITION BY Name) as Total from cte
order by Total desc, Name, [CountItem] desc
```

but I only want to get the top 10 Names with the highest total like the one below:

```
+-------+-------------------------------+-------+-------+
| Name  |           Emergency           | Count | Total |
+-------+-------------------------------+-------+-------+
| PLB   | No                            |     7 |    15 |
| PLB   | No Hot Water                  |     4 |    15 |
| PLB   | Resident Locked Out           |     2 |    15 |
| PLB   | Overflowing Tub               |     1 |    15 |
| PLB   | No Heat                       |     1 |    15 |
| GG    | Broken Lock - Exterior        |     6 |     6 |
| BOA   | Broken Lock - Exterior        |     2 |     4 |
| BOA   | Garage Door not working       |     1 |     4 |
| BOA   | Resident Locked Out           |     1 |     4 |
| 15777 | Smoke  Alarm not working      |     3 |     3 |
| FP    | No air conditioning           |     2 |     3 |
| FP    | Flood                         |     1 |     3 |
| KB    | No electrical power           |     2 |     3 |
| KB    | No                            |     1 |     3 |
| MEM   | Noise Complaint               |     3 |     3 |
| ANG   | Parking Issue                 |     2 |     2 |
| ALL   | Smoke  Alarm not working      |     2 |     2 |
| AAS   | No air conditioning           |     1 |     2 |
| AAS   | Toilet - Clogged (1 Bathroom) |     1 |     2 |
+-------+-------------------------------+-------+-------+
```

**Note: I'm not after unique values. As you can see from the example above it gets the top 10 names from a very long table.**

What I want to happen is assign a row id for each name so all PLB above will have a row id of 1, GG = 2, BOA = 3, ...

So on my final select I will only add the where clause `where row id <= 10`. I already tried `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY Name)` but it's assigning 1 to every unique Name it encounters.

Comment: post your input data and expected result clearly

Comment: The expected result is the table above. The input data is the same as the table above only longer.

Comment: check my edited ans.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
    ;with cte as (
    SELECT [Name],
            [Emergency],
            count([Emergency]) as [CountItem]
    FROM tableA
    GROUP BY [Name], [Emergency]),
    ct as (
    select Name,[Emergency],[Count],SUM([CountItem]) OVER(PARTITION BY PropertyName) as Total from cte
    ),
    ctname as (
    select dense_rank() over ( order by total, name ) as RankName, Name,[Emergency],[Count], total from ct )
    select * from ctname where rankname < 11
```

Comment: I tried your answer but it's giving me the whole original list it just added a new column `rankname`

Comment: that `rankname` is for your filter, hope rank name is added like `1,2,3...` as you wanted.

Comment: unfortunately, it didn't do that as expected. it added `1` as `rankname` for each entry.

Comment: actually you don't need `patition by`. I think `order by` would be sufficient. See my updated ans.

Comment: it changed but the `rankname` shows like this:

`1 | PLB`
`2 | PLB`
`3 | PLB`
`3 | PLB`
`4 | PLB`